# How to refresh/Update Serialize Java Object in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

For storing the serilaizable java object i m using below code

```
if(sharedpreferences.getString(ComplexObjectXMl,"")!=null) {

                Serializer serializer = new Persister();
                MyObject example = null;
                try {
                    example = serializer.read(MyObject .class, sharedpreferences.getString(ComplexObjectXMl,""));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent i1 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
                new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

In MyAsyncTask i m storing the XmlDataOverHttp in sharedPreferences. Will it get updated everytime if i like do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can compare byte array of those object. one coming from shared preference and other which is latest.

```
  byte[] array = new Gson().toJson(latestObject).getBytes(); //your lattest byte array
    byte[] secondArray = new Gson().toJson(objectConvertedFromSharedPreferenceOLD).getBytes();
    if (Arrays.equals(array, secondArray))

        System.out.println("They are same");
else
 System.out.println("Nope...");
```

and as you said you can use service or shared preference to check hourly update in oncreateView() but it only happens when user open your app(between hour it will call api for list items)

```
    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences
                (Dashboard.this);
        long lastUpdateTime = mSettings.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);
        /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
        if ((lastUpdateTime + (3600000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

        /* Save current timestamp for next Check*/
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
            lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime);
            editor.commit();

        /* Start Update for listview your URL to fetch data and then you can check and compare object 
also you can use swipeRefreshLayout so user can also refresh data*/
            //asyncRequestTime.execute(URL);
        }
```

Comment: Its theobject which has all information about app. I dont want to fetch that object from server everytime and only want to load when its get changed on server. Thats why storing it in shared preference

Comment: If i would be able to refresh this object every hour that will help a lots but not everytime. as per method i need to compare the object everytime

Comment: does it helped you ? or you want to use service that run within hour to check updated data.

Comment: can u check the updates questionand let me know If i will get always get the latest object stored in shared preference. Will my                 new MyAsyncTask().execute(); will always get called and stored the 
updated XmlDataOverHttp in shared  preference

Comment: if new MyAsyncTask().execute() response stored in preference of course . you are calling it every time and storing data in preferences.when activity open if code is in  oncreate().

Comment: you can use second code snippet which i give. if it is in hour then call api to load data or in else read shared preference and bind data with listview and kindly also implement android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout in your listview. if it is all that case of caching