# How to make ListView to refresh after every 5 sec when data come from a server

Tags: java, android, listview, refresh

I have `ListView` which have data . Data come from server and I want the `ListView` to update after every 5 sec. How to do this? I am new to android development. Please help me. Here is my code...

```
    protected void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < peoples.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
            final String dataaaa = rcdata.getText().toString().trim();
            HashMap<String, String> user_data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            user_data.put(TAG_DATA, data);
            personList.add(user_data);
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                DataSendActivity.this, personList, R.layout.layout_chat,
                new String[]{TAG_DATA},
                new int[]{R.id.data}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to fetch data from server and update listview.

Comment: fetch data using service and use notifidatasetchanges()

Comment: data fatch correctly but issue is with listview refresh

Comment: final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 5000 );
    }
}, 5000 );                    i use this code on create but notifiydatasetchange() can not resolve here

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method to invalidate the list's adapter as follows:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 5000 );
    }
}, 5000 );
```

You must only update UI in the main (UI) thread.

Comment: @MasoomBacha in your `OnCreate` create one simple method and call `Handler` for that place. It will refresh the listview every `5 second`.

Comment: @MasoomBacha for more detail visit this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916084/android-update-listview-items-every-1-minute

Comment: Semi colon missing in handler declaration.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this question and comment [How to refresh/Update Serialize Java Object in sharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243996/how-to-refresh-update-serialize-java-object-in-sharedpreferences/37247309?noredirect=1#comment62029302_37247309). the user want the same. however it is good to use loader with service for that kind of problem calling asyncTask within minute is not good. also theres is a sample project you can check this https://github.com/Michenux/YourAppIdea also available in playstore which check for data changes from server.